# How to Determine Covariance Matrix $Q$ and $R$ in Kalman Filter

Tags: kalman-filters, sensor, bayesian-estimation

I am implementing getting orientation from smartphone. I want to use Kalman filter and should determine process noise covariance matrix $Q$ and measurement noise covariance matrix $R$. (newbie to Kalman filter)

I don't have any idea how to determine $Q$. What I think about $R$ is as follows:

state vector : quaternion from (accelerometer + gyroscope)

(1) My phone is stand still. I get covaraince matrix from Matlab

1.0e-04 *

```
0.0000    0.0005    0.0035   -0.0000
0.0005    0.0063    0.0411   -0.0002
0.0035    0.0411    0.2881   -0.0014
```

-0.0000   -0.0002   -0.0014    0.0000

(2) My phone had been moved for 5 seconds.

covariance matrix is

```
0.0417   -0.0533   -0.0008   -0.0014
-0.0533    0.0784    0.0015    0.0018
-0.0008    0.0015    0.0001    0.0001
-0.0014    0.0018    0.0001    0.0001
```

Is there anyone to help?

---

(added)

Details are omitted.

## case 1: Kalman Filter

The row data from my phone is $p, q, r$ (angular velocity). I omit the conversion equation between angular velocity and quaternion.
\begin{align*}
x_{k+1} &= Ax_k+w_k \\
z_k &= Hx_k + \nu_k \\
Q &: \text{ covariance matrix for }w_k\\
R &: \text{ covariance matrix for }\nu_k
\end{align*}

$$ \begin{bmatrix}\dot q_1\\\dot q_2\\\dot q_3\\\dot q_4\end{bmatrix}=\frac 12 \begin{bmatrix} 0&-p&-q&-r\\p&0&r&-q\\q&-r&0&p\\r&q&-p&0 \end{bmatrix}     
\begin{bmatrix} q_1\\ q_2\\ q_3\\ q_4\end{bmatrix}$$

$$ \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} q_1\\ q_2\\ q_3\\ q_4\end{bmatrix}_{k+1}}_{x_{k+1}}=\underbrace{\left( I + \Delta t\cdot \frac 12 \begin{bmatrix} 0&-p&-q&-r\\p&0&r&-q\\q&-r&0&p\\r&q&-p&0 \end{bmatrix}\right)}_{A}
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} q_1\\ q_2\\ q_3\\ q_4\end{bmatrix}_k}_{x_k} $$
$$ H=I$$
My guess for covariance matrix is as follows: (but I don' know how to infer..)
$$ Q = 0.001I, \quad R=10I.$$

## case 2: Extended Kalman Filter

\begin{align*}x_{k+1} &= f(x_k) + w_k \\
z_k &= h(x_k) + \nu_k\\
Q &: \text{ covariance matrix for }w_k\\
R &: \text{ covariance matrix for }\nu_k
\end{align*}
$$ A = \left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right|_{x_k} ,\quad H = \left.\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}\right|_{x_k} $$
\begin{align*} \begin{bmatrix} \dot \phi\\ \dot \theta\\ \dot \varphi \end{bmatrix}&=
\begin{bmatrix} 1&\sin\phi\tan\theta & \cos\phi\tan\theta \\
0&\cos\phi & -\sin\phi \\ 
0&\sin\phi\sec\theta & \cos\phi\sec\theta \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}p\\ q\\  r \end{bmatrix} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix} p+q\sin\phi\tan\theta+r\cos\phi\tan\theta \\
q\cos\phi-r\sin\phi \\ 
q\sin\phi\sec\theta + r\cos\phi\sec\theta \end{bmatrix} \\
&= f(x) + w
\end{align*}
$$z = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\phi\\\theta\\\varphi\end{bmatrix}+\nu = Hx + \nu $$
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial\phi} & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial\theta} & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial\varphi} \\
\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial\phi} & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial\theta} & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial\varphi} \\
\frac{\partial f_3}{\partial\phi} & \frac{\partial f_3}{\partial\theta} & \frac{\partial f_3}{\partial\varphi}
\end{bmatrix} $$

(I emphasize that details are omitted.) In this case, also I don't know how to infere $Q, R$.

Comment: The direct use of a quaternion in a Kalman Filter is bad news - a quaternion is not a vector and the "states" are not independent, which essentially destroys the assumptions of the filter.  Accordingly, the covariance is meaningless.

Comment: Instead, formulate the filter in terms of *error states*, or if you insist on using direct attitude terms, use an [Extended Kalman Filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Kalman_filter) with [Euler Angles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles).  There's some serious maths here, but textbooks from [Groves](http://www.amazon.com/Principles-Multisensor-Integrated-Navigation-Applications/dp/1608070050) and [Farrell](http://www.amazon.com/Aided-Navigation-High-Rate-Sensors/dp/0071493298) are quite useful.

Comment: Thank for your comment. Actually, eve with that, how to determine $Q$ and $R$?

Comment: You will need to post your process and measurement model (as $\LaTeX$, not code) before I can make an informed comment.

Comment: Okay, I've added equations.

Comment: Case 1 cannot be used as a Kalman Filter - the quaternion is not a vector - the components are not independent. There are [ways around that](http://www.csee.ogi.edu/~rudmerwe/pubs/pdf/vanderMerwe_SPKF_ION-AM-2004.pdf) but the techniques are quite advanced.

Comment: Let us work with case 2 then. Can you identify where the gyro and accelerometer measurements are taken into account?

Comment: Why is the quaternion not a vector? I used Case 1 and got a reasonable result. What is the problem?

Comment: I got accelerometr values from which I got euler angle $\phi, \theta$.
Then run EKF whose parameters are $\phi, \theta$, p, q, r, dt where p,q,r are measured gyroscope values.

Comment: "Why is the quaternion not a vector?" Because adding two (unit) quaternions does not give a unit quaternion. Accordingly, the KF update equation, $x(k+1|k+1) = x(k+1|k) + W (z(k+1) - z(k+1|k+1))$ Is all but guaranteed to fall over.

Comment: On Case 2: Are your equations in discrete time, as required by the KF family?

Comment: On Case 1: Is it true that if something is not a vector, it cannot be a state variable of Kalman filter?

Comment: On Case 2: I don't know exactly 'KF family', but equations are in discrete time.

Comment: On Case 1:  For optimality of the KF, the states must belong to [vector space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space). Of course, engineers have to make things work and sometimes have to accept a sub-optimal solution. If it looks *close enough* to a vector, where the states can be *approximately* added and scaled, then a KF can often give adequate performance.  In this instance, an example is a *attitude error* state, which is a nominal deviation from a reference attitude. See references above for details.

Comment: On Case 1 (continued): If the states *cannot* be added to anything meaningful, then a KF cannot be used, except using some [advanced (and nasty) tricks](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6811532&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fxpls%2Fabs_all.jsp%3Farnumber%3D6811532). This is exactly the case for attitude quaternions - clearly (as mentioned above) the state update is completely meaningless.

Comment: On Case 2: Your state transition equations as listed are in continuous time.  Next hint: your $[p, q, r]^T$ can be considered a *control input*. Next hint after that: Consider your gyros to have white noise in addition to your actual measurements. What happens?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will check it. As a newbie for kalman filter, it is confusing. Following your comment, my book has an error.

Comment: On case 2, implementation is in discrete time. For the simple description, I omit implementation details. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19952/discussion-between-damien-and-topy).

Comment: Please see the reports arXiv:1503.04313v1.pdf, arXiv:1505.07201v1.pdf and arXiv:1505.07208v1.pdf. and the papers in SADHANA December 2016 issues.

Answer (score 2):

R depends on the sensor sensitivity. If this is a real world problem this can be obtained from the manufacturer. If not use the identity matrix multiplied by a scalar that is less than 1.

Q is the covariance of the process noise. Again if this is a real world problem this can be obtained in the noise level in the states of the system at steady state. if not you can assume Q is zero matrix. A non zero Q helps achieve good convergency characteristics [as explained here.](https://simondlevy.academic.wlu.edu/kalman-tutorial/the-extended-kalman-filter-an-interactive-tutorial-for-non-experts-part-14/)